# Writing Data into a File on Hololens

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, hololens

in my Hololens app i want to write data into a file which i can then view over the Device Portal. The Data contains just the time from one airtap on a special object to another airtap.
The problem ist that there will be no file created in the Device Portal under /LocalAppData/YourApp/LocalState

Thanks in advance

Jonathan

```
public void StopTime()

{

    TimeSpan ts = time.Elapsed;
    time.Stop();
    path = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "Messdaten.txt");
    using (TextWriter writer = File.CreateText(path))
    {
        writer.Write(ts);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your StopTime method actually being called? Also, according to the documentation, `Application.persistentDataPath` is not resolved to a path like `/LocalAppData/YourApp/LocalState`.

Comment: Try writing it to your desktop.

Comment: @elgonzo the path is fine .. it is different on the lens itself but they display the path like this in the DevicePortal

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use a `FileStream` and a `StreamWriter` and make sure the `FileMode.Create` is set.

See also [How to write text to a file](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-write-text-to-a-file) for more approaches

```
using (var file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(file, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        writer.Write(content);
    }
}
```

With that I never had any trouble on the HoloLens so far.

You also might want to use something like `ts.ToString()` in order to format the value to your needs.

---

Alternatively you could also try Unity's [Windows.File](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Windows.File.html) (only available for UWP) but than you need to have `byte[]` as input. E.g. [from here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/57873da4-b97b-4de4-82fb-c23233d1e4c6/csharp-convert-datetime-and-timespan-to-short-byte-byte-and-int-using-visual-studio-2008-sp1?forum=csharpgeneral)

```
long c = ts.Ticks;
byte[] d = BitConverter.GetBytes(c);

File.WriteAllBytes(path, d);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i got it working with your help!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to do is to use `File.WriteAllText` method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=netframework-4.7.2

Obviously there are many ways that could work but it is good to stick to the simplest solution.